# Breaking a row into multiple rows based on date value

Tags: sql

I am trying to implement a logic which breaks row into multiple rows based on date values
for eg. I have 1 record like this

```
Col1   Col2   Start_dat    End_dat     Last_dat    Next_dat
=====  ====   =========    =======     ========    ======== 
A      B      01-01-13     01-31-13    01-04-13    02-04-13
```

Now I am breaking above record in two row.

```
Col1   Col2   New_Start_dat    NewEnd_dat     Last_dat    Next_dat
=====  ====   =============    ==========     ========    ======== 
A      B      01-04-13         01-31-13       01-04-13    02-04-13

A      B      02-01-13         02-04-13       01-04-13    02-04-13
```

Note :- dates are in mm-dd-yy format.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really explain your logic.  I think it is something like:

```
select col1, col2, last_dat, as New_Start_dat, End_Dat as NewEnd_dat, last_dat, next_dat
from t
union all
select col1, col2, End_Dat + 1 as NewStart_dat, next_dat as NewEnd_Dat, last_dat, next_dat;
from t
```

In many databases, adding `1` to a date adds one day.  It might also be something like `dateadd(day, 1, End_Dat)` or `dateadd(1, Ent_Dat)`.

Also, this assumes that the dates are really stored in a date format and the `dd-mm-yy` format is for output purposes only.

Comment: Thanks Gordon I implemented above logic in my query its working.